# jQuery override event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, preventdefault

I have a form that, when submitted, goes through the usual `e.preventDefault()` and sends an ajax request instead. However, if this ajax request returns a certain condition, I want the form to be submitted normally. How do I achieve this?

```
// Submit handler
$(".reserveer_form").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr("action"),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      if($(".messagered",data).length > 0){
        var errors = $(".messagered",data);
        $(".gegevens").before(errors);
      } else {
          // SUBMIT THE FORM!
      } 
      
    }
  });

})
```

Comment: $(".reserveer_form").submit()?

Comment: @jeschafe That could cause an infinte loop...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Invoke the native `submit` method on the form, so that it doesn't trigger the jQuery handler.

```
$.ajax({
    context: this, // <-- set the context.
    url: $(this).attr("action"),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        if ($(".messagered", data).length > 0) {
            var errors = $(".messagered", data);
            $(".gegevens").before(errors);
        } else {
            this.submit(); // <-- submit the form
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your comment says you change a form variable, you could start your `submit` handler by checking that same form variable. If it is changed, just `return true`. If not, continue with the current handler.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`submit()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.submit) or forms:

```
$(".reserveer_form").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var form = this,
      $form = $(form);

  $.ajax({
    url: $form.attr("action"),
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      var errors = $(".messagered", data);
      if (errors.length > 0){
        $(".gegevens").before(errors);
      } else {
        form.submit();
      }
    }
  });
})
```

However, this seems to be a strange ajax request. First, you send the form (serialized, via ajax) to the server, and when the response contains no errors you send it again? The server would process it twice (and act twice, depending on your form). Also, the user does not get a message that his input is already processed - he clicks "submit", and it always takes a time until it is visibly submitted (where he even could change some input).

Comment: If you trigger the jQuery handler, you'll have an infinite loop.

Comment: oops, fixed. At first I only wanted use it directly, but then I cached the jQuery instance in $form and didn't recognize that would change the behaviour :-)

Comment: I'd remove the DV if I could, but it wasn't mine. Although I wouldn't consider this request to be strange. It's just doing the necessary server-side validation, and rejecting the submission if there were errors.

Comment: ...only that it submits effectively the form, even to the actual url. There is no big difference to a non-ajax submit, but if the first "validation" request was successful it will be performed a second time, just dropping the (valuable) results.